# Geofirestore with advanced queries

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I am considering the option to change my firestore collection structure to include geoquery in my application. 
geofirestore needs a specific structure :

```
 interface GeoDocument {
    g: string;
    l: GeoPoint;
    d: DocumentData;
  }
```

I know that geofirestore does not allow using where clause to retrieve documents. however, I would like to give the users options to see information based on the location or search ( using standalone queries) 
in my existing application, I have many queries using different indexes to search in my collection.
Can I still be able to use my existing queries and indexes without any performance issues if I use geofirestore document. :

```
interface GeoDocument {
    g: string;
    l: GeoPoint;
    d: DocumentData;
  }
```

Comment: Not a massive difference to the types of queries you make, but if you try geofirestore v4.x.x the data structure now looks like:

```TypeScript
interface GeoDocumentData {
  g: {
    geohash: string;
    geopoint: GeoPoint;
  };
  [field: string]: any;
  }
```

Now everything is at the top level of the data structure inside of the `g` property. Hopefully that will allow you to add geofirestore without needing to modify your indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most applications, you might face performance problems, in case you have a lot of documents and the queries are returning too many of them. In case you have a situation like this, your application might have a performance problem.

In case the searches are individual and you will be expecting specific and not thousands of returns of data, you should be fine. In addition to that, I would recommend you to take a look at this article [here](https://medium.com/@chintak3699/how-i-created-geo-firestore-query-library-to-list-nearby-items-with-native-query-9366859f95b), where there are some examples and methods to avoid performance issues.

Let me know if the information helped you!